# Can't add a row to a jTable even when using getModel

Tags: java, swing, jtable, defaulttablemodel

I've been searching through this website for numerous hours now on how to get my button to an a row to an already existing table, this table created by simply clicking the swing Controls, and adding a table and altering the fields through the properties.

The table's variable name is 'table'.

And when confronted with this line of code:
`table.getModel().insertRow(table.getRowCount(),new Object[]{nome[i],data[i]});`

The 'insertRow' part is redded and I can't seem to fix it.

```
         private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
           String direcdate=direc1.getText();


    File folder = new File(direcdate);
    File[] listOfFiles=folder.listFiles();


    String[] nome = new String[250];
    String[] data = new String[250];
    int i=0;


    for (File listOfFile : listOfFiles) {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

        if (listOfFile.isFile()) {

            nome[i]= listOfFile.getName ();
            data[i] =sdf.format(listOfFile.lastModified());


            i++;    
        }

        else if (listOfFile.isDirectory()) {

            nome[i]= "Folder: " + listOfFile.getName ();
            data[i] =sdf.format(listOfFile.lastModified());
            i++;
        }
    }


for(int increm=0;increm<i;increm++)
       {
      table.getModel().insertRow(table.getRowCount(),new Object[]{nome[i],data[i]});



            }


           }
```

Any ideas or suggestions?

EDIT: where the table model is located:
           public class GAPAC_TESTE extends javax.swing.JFrame {

```
   public GAPAC_TESTE() {


    initComponents();
    ultimaalt.setText("0");
    jTextPane2.setText("Após escolher a diretoria, escolha uma das opções.");
  DefaultTableModel model = new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel();
table = new javax.swing.JTable(model);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
table.getModel().
```

That method return a TableModel. Did you look at the API for the TableModel interface? It does not contain an `insertRow(...)` method.

The `DefaultTableModel` has the `insertRow(...)` method. So assuming your table is using a DefaultTableModel the code would be:

```
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableMode)table.getModel();
model.insertRow(...);
```

Don't always write you code in a single statmentment. Break the statement up into multiple statements so you understand exactly which part of the statement causes the problem and it makes sure you assign the variable to the proper class.

Comment: This is my current for cycle `for(int increm=0;increm<i;increm++)
{
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)table.getModel();
model.insertRow(table.getRowCount(),new Object[]{nome[i],data[i]});


     
}`

And it still does not print unto the table.

Comment: @TheRevguin if you want to insert a row at the end, use `addRow` instead of `insertRow`. Also, I haven't tried, but I would imagine using `getRowCount` for `insertRow` would cause an `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` exception, as that row doesn't exist. Are you getting this exception?

Comment: @TheRevguin, did you verify that the code is executing properly? If you have the reference to the table that is displayed in the GUI then the code will work. Maybe your table reference is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you implement a [`TableModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html), you will be able to exactly determine how data is added and which data types are displayed in your table.

Comment: I've been having problems with adding a tablemodel to an already existing table, so I've been trying this method.

Can you show me an example of the alternative?

Edit: I just need to know what to do next, I've been at this impass for a long time, and it's come to the point where I can't advance without this working.

Comment: Did you write the existing table model, or was it provided? The reason it is not working at the moment, is because JTable's getModel method returns a `TableModel` which does not have an `insertRow` function. Can you paste where you originally set the table model?

Comment: I'll add it unto the original post.

Comment: In that case you'll have to use `getTableModel` and cast the return value to a `DefaultTableModel`, you should then be able to add the row as you wanted :)

Comment: Now, even with the tablemodel set as DefaultTableModel, it does not show errors, yet no row is added, nor is there any red text when I press the button.